# Set transaction isolation in Wildfly local datasource

Tags: java, transactions, isolation, sails-mssqlserver

I am using Wildfly 13 with a MS SQLServer database (sqljdbc driver 4.0.0)

I am trying to set the transaction isolation for the connections created by Wildfly.

The local datasource configuration is

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/SOMDS" pool-name="SOMDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
   <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=vmscs_Eneos_2;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false</connection-url>
   <driver>sqljdbc4.jar</driver>
   <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
   <pool>
       <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
       <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
       <prefill>true</prefill>
   </pool>
   <security>
       <user-name>som</user-name>
       <password>som</password>
   </security>
</datasource>
```

But all the connections are created with the default transaction isolation level (TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED) and this is never changed.

Any idea about what could be wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to confirm that the configuration is correct.
I was checking the transaction isolation level of the created connections using the SQL Server Profiler but I don't why this always show "read committed".
But when I executed a query over the table sys.dm_exec_sessions I could check that the transaction isolation level was setted (transaction_isolation_level column = 1)

Best regards
Dario